# Dynamic connection string in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2017

I am having the following problem with populating a dynamic file path for an XML file from a SSIS variable.

In Visual Studio 2017 I have an Execute SQL Task with a MS SQL stored procedure that returns two columns. The first column is a date (stored as a string) and the second is a URL. These two columns (single row) populate SSIS variables and are mapped on the Result Set tab of the Script Task. The next step is script task that uses the URL from the variable to download an xml file from a web service. The xml file is stored using a file Connection Manager. The connection string for the file is an expression that should be using the 1st variable (`User::rateDate`) from the Execute SQL Task

*Connection String expression:*

```
@[User::xmlFileLocation] + "ExchangeRates-" +  @[User::rateDate]  + ".xml"
```

This evaluates to

> \server\ExchangeRates\ExchangeRates-.xml

XML file should be saved as `ExchangeRates-2017-12-19.xml` with `2017-12-19` being the result of the stored procedure, but instead the XML file is saved as `ExchangeRates-.xml`

If I manually populate the `User::rateDate` variable it will use that in the Connection String, but I haven't been able to get it to populate from the stored procedure result.

The date generated is part of the URL generation too so I want this both created in the same place, i.e. I don't want to assign the file name via some `GETDATE()` logic in the expression.

I have confirmed the variable is being populated is a Script Task C# pop up.

I have confirmed that it is not a date/string issue by changing the stored procedure result to an explicit string, like "test". It still doesn't get added to the Connection String.

Thanks, Tim

[image: Main tab]
[image: Results tab]
[image: Variables]
[image: 2017]

Comment: If you execute the stored procedure from SQL it returns values? also can you add a screenshot of the variables mapping tab and the main form in the execute SQL Task editor?

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally created two identically named variables in _different scopes_. You might be populating the variable in one scope, then reading it from a different scope. I've done it before and it took me a long time to work out.

Comment: Thanks, I've added those screenshots and checked on the variable scope, that would be a tricky one. Yes, the stored procedure returns values if executed in SSMS and populates the User::serverURL properly do download the xml.

Comment: @TimPeters is the stored procedure return values as a select statement result (table) or output parameters? can you show the part of the stored procedure that contains the result generation?

Comment: @timPeters i changed the tag [tag:ssis-2017] tp [tag:ssis-2008] because from the screenshots i think you are using the business intelligence development studio 2008

Comment: @Hadi, nope it's 2017. I'll give your suggestions below a shot. Thanks

Comment: @TimPeters have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide 2 solutions based on the Stored Procedure type:

## Stored Procedure with a Select Statement

*I will assume that you are using a Stored procedure that contains a SELECT statement that return a Table of 2 columns: `ServerURL` and `rateDate`*

In this case  you have to insert the result of this select statement into a temp table, then read from these temp table, as example:

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL(ServerURL varchar(4000), rateDate varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #TBL EXEC pr_rateDate

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #TBL
```

In this way your variables mapping should work

## Stored Procedure with Output Parameters

*I will assume that you are using a stored procedure which require 2 output parameters to be passed, example:*

```
EXEC sp_rateDate @ServerURL OUTPUT, @rateDate OUTPUT
```

So you have to use the following SQL statemment:

```
EXEC sp_rateDate ? OUTPUT, ? OUTPUT
```

and you have to add 2 output parameters in the **Parameter Mapping** tab

## Useful Links

- [Parameters and Return Codes in the Execute SQL Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502(v=sql.110).aspx) *Read Using Parameters with Stored Procedures part*
- [SQL Assist - SSIS Execute SQL Task](https://sqlassist.wordpress.com/tag/full-result-set/)
- [Map Result Sets to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141689(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [How to Execute Stored Procedure in SSIS Execute SQL Task in SSIS](https://mindmajix.com/ssis/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-in-ssis-execute-sql-task)
- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)

Comment: This worked, but I ended up modifying the connection string in a C# script and not via an expression in the file Connection Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype of variable `User::rateDate` to datetime. Then, change your connection string expression to the following:

```
@[User::xmlFileLocation] + 
"ExchangeRates-" + 
(DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",@[User::rateDate]) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",@[User::rateDate]) ,2) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",@[User::rateDate]),2) +
".xml"
```